# Ruby scan with optional match matches, returns nil except for optional

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm running the following to catch a series of numerical values (floats and integers) in a string:

Example:

```
x = "This is the 1st string with 2 quotes and took 3.4 seconds to write."
```

Running

```
x.scan(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)
```

returns

```
[[nil], [nil], [".4"]]
```

but I'm looking for

```
[["1"], ["2"], ["3.4"]]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

> If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of
>   the matched string, `$&`. If the pattern contains groups, each individual
>   result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

Since your pattern contains a capture group, you're getting the latter behavior. Making the group non-capturing gives you what you want.

```
x.scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)
```